# Module for isotopic masses and abundances

Tags: haskell, enum, physics

I have written a small module for accessing data on isotope masses and relative abundances. My long term aim is to build tools in Haskell for working with mass spectrometry data. Any comments on how to improve this module will be greatly appreciated. I am considering uploading this to Hackage, though I want to be sure it is of sufficient quality.

https://github.com/Michaelt293/Element-isotopes

The relevent code is provided below.

```haskell
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Maybe as Maybe
import qualified Data.List as List


type IsotopeMass = Double
type IsotopeAbundance = Double
type ElementName = String
type AtomicNumber = Integer
type NumberOfNeutrons = Integer
type IsotopeData = (AtomicNumber, NumberOfNeutrons)
type IntegerMass = Integer


data Isotope = Isotope { isotopeData      :: IsotopeData
                       , isotopeMass      :: IsotopeMass
                       , isotopeAbundance :: IsotopeAbundance
                       } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data Element = Element { atomicNumber     :: AtomicNumber
                       , elementName      :: ElementName
                       , isotopes         :: [Isotope]
                       } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data ElementSymbol = H  | He | Li | Be | B  | C  | N  | O  | F  | Ne | Na | Mg |
                     Al | Si | P  | S  | Cl | Ar | K  | Ca | Sc | Ti | V  | Cr |
                     Mn | Fe | Co | Ni | Cu | Zn | Ga | Ge | As | Se | Br | Kr |
                     Rb | Sr | Y  | Zr | Nb | Mo | Tc | Ru | Rh | Pd | Ag | Cd |
                     In | Sn | Sb | Te | I  | Xe | Cs | Ba | La | Ce | Pr | Nd |
                     Pm | Sm | Eu | Gd | Tb | Dy | Ho | Er | Tm | Yb | Lu | Hf |
                     Ta | W  | Re | Os | Ir | Pt | Au | Hg | Tl | Pb | Bi | Th |
                     Pa | U  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
```

Data on isotope masses and abundances is provided in a map (only the first three elements are given as an example).

```haskell
elements = Map.fromList
  [ (H,  Element 1  "hydrogen"     [ Isotope (1, 0)     1.00782503223  0.999885   
                                   , Isotope (1, 1)     2.01410177812  0.000115 ])
  , (He, Element 2  "helium"       [ Isotope (2, 1)     3.0160293201   0.00000134
                                   , Isotope (2, 2)     4.00260325413  0.99999866 ])
  , (Li, Element 3  "lithium"      [ Isotope (3, 3)     6.0151228874   0.0759
                                   , Isotope (3, 4)     7.0160034366   0.9241 ])
```

Functions for working with the isotope data -

```haskell
lookupElement :: ElementSymbol -> Element
lookupElement elemSym = Maybe.fromJust $ Map.lookup elemSym elements

getElementName :: ElementSymbol -> ElementName
getElementName elemSym = elementName . lookupElement $ elemSym

getAtomicNumber :: ElementSymbol -> AtomicNumber
getAtomicNumber elemSym = atomicNumber . lookupElement $ elemSym

getIsotopes :: ElementSymbol -> [Isotope]
getIsotopes elemSym = isotopes . lookupElement $ elemSym

mostAbunantIsotope :: ElementSymbol -> Isotope
mostAbunantIsotope elemSym = isotopeList !! indexOfIsotope
    where isotopeList = getIsotopes elemSym
          indexOfIsotope = Maybe.fromJust $ List.elemIndex 
                           (maximum $ map isotopeAbundance $ getIsotopes elemSym)
                           (map isotopeAbundance $ getIsotopes elemSym)

selectIsotope :: ElementSymbol -> IntegerMass -> Isotope
selectIsotope elemSym number = isotopeList !! indexOfIsotope
    where isotopeList = getIsotopes elemSym
          indexOfIsotope = Maybe.fromJust $ 
                           List.elemIndex number (isotopeIntegerMasses elemSym)

monoisotopicMass :: ElementSymbol -> IsotopeMass
monoisotopicMass elemSym = isotopeMass $ mostAbunantIsotope elemSym

nominalMass :: ElementSymbol -> IntegerMass
nominalMass elemSym = sumPair . isotopeData $ mostAbunantIsotope elemSym
    where sumPair (atomicNum, protons) = atomicNum + protons

isotopeMasses :: ElementSymbol -> [IsotopeMass]
isotopeMasses elemSym = map isotopeMass $ getIsotopes elemSym

isotopeIntegerMasses :: ElementSymbol -> [IntegerMass]
isotopeIntegerMasses elemSym = map (sumPair . isotopeData) $ getIsotopes elemSym
    where sumPair (atomicNum, protons) = atomicNum + protons

 averageAtomicMass :: ElementSymbol -> IsotopeMass
 averageAtomicMass elemSym = sum [isotopeMass x * isotopeAbundance x |
                              x <- getIsotopes elemSym]
```

Edit: I have made some changes to the functions based on the suggestions of Erik Allik -

```haskell
lookupElement :: ElementSymbol -> Element
lookupElement = (!) elements

elementName :: ElementSymbol -> ElementName
elementName = name . lookupElement

atomicNumber :: ElementSymbol -> AtomicNumber
atomicNumber = elementAtomicNumber . lookupElement

isotopes :: ElementSymbol -> [Isotope]
isotopes = elementIsotopes . lookupElement

mostAbunantIsotope :: ElementSymbol -> Isotope
mostAbunantIsotope sym = isotopeList !! indexOfIsotope
    where isotopeList = isotopes sym
          abundances = isotopeAbundance <$> isotopeList
          indexOfIsotope = fromJust $ elemIndex (maximum abundances) abundances

selectIsotope :: ElementSymbol -> IntegerMass -> Isotope
selectIsotope sym mass = isotopeList !! indexOfIsotope
    where isotopeList = isotopes sym
          indexOfIsotope = fromJust $ elemIndex mass (isotopeIntegerMasses sym)

monoisotopicMass :: ElementSymbol -> IsotopeMass
monoisotopicMass = isotopeMass . mostAbunantIsotope

nominalMass :: ElementSymbol -> IntegerMass
nominalMass = massNumber . isotopeData . mostAbunantIsotope

isotopeMasses :: ElementSymbol -> [IsotopeMass]
isotopeMasses sym = isotopeMass <$> isotopes sym

isotopeIntegerMasses :: ElementSymbol -> [IntegerMass]
isotopeIntegerMasses sym = massNumber . isotopeData <$> isotopes sym

massNumber :: (AtomicNumber, NumberOfNeutrons) -> IntegerMass
massNumber (atomicNum, protons) = atomicNum + protons

averageAtomicMass :: ElementSymbol -> IsotopeMass
averageAtomicMass elemSym = sum [isotopeMass x * isotopeAbundance x |
                              x <- isotopes elemSym]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just trivial changes but how about:

---

Rely more on point-free, for example

```hs
monoisotopicMass = isotopeMass . mostAbunantIsotope

isotopeIntegerMasses = map (sumPair . isotopeData) . getIsotopes
  where sumPair (atomicNum, protons) = atomicNum + protons
```

---

Use names such as `isotopes` instead of `getIsotopes` etc.

`getIsotopes` feels imperative; consider `map getIsotopes symbols` vs `map isotopes symbols` or even `isotopes <$> symbols`

---

I personally really prefer `fmap` and `<$>` over `map`. What's nice about `<$>` is that it makes it appear as you're applying a function to a list:

```hs
sqrt <$> [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

which reads a little bit like

```hs
sqrt $ 2.0
```